# Count unique/dinstinct words into a new column

Tags: r, count, unique

I have a dataset with a column containing a set of countries in each row. Sometimes countries are repeated more than once, and I would like to count the number of unique countries in each row of my dataset below:

```
> class(address_countries2$address_countries)
[1] "character"

> head(address_countries2)
                    address_countries
1                         China China
2                   China China China
3                         China China
4                         China China
5 China China China China China China
6                China China Uk China
```

the desired output would be a new column like this:

```
                    address_countries n_countries
1                         China China           1
2                   China China China           1
3                         China China           1
4                         China China           1
5 China China China China China China           1
6                China China Uk China           2
```

this code gives me the number of words inside each row:

```
address_countries2 <- address_countries2 %>% 
  select(address_countries) %>% 
  mutate(n_countries = str_count(address_countries, boundary("word")))


> head(address_countries2)
                    address_countries n_countries
1                         China China           2
2                   China China China           3
3                         China China           2
4                         China China           2
5 China China China China China China           6
6                China China Uk China           4
```

I have tried adding unique() as well as n_distinct() and distinct() with str_count() but I get this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `n_countries` must be length 34760 (the number of rows) or one, not 39
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Stange, you accepted an answer that is not complete and can not be checked if it works ....

Comment: it works. only thing to change is that "ist_country" into "address_countries" and it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Your data.frame

```
address_countries2<-data.frame(address_countries=c("Chian","China China","China UK"))
```

Count number of countries:

```
list_country<-strsplit(as.character(address_countries2$address_countries)," ")
list_country
[[1]]
[1] "Chian"

[[2]]
[1] "China" "China"

[[3]]
[1] "China" "UK"
```

Adding "n_countries" column

```
address_countries2$n_countries<-unlist(lapply(lapply(list_country, unique),length))
```

The output

```
address_countries2
        address_countries n_countries
        1             Chian           1
        2       China China           1
        3          China UK           2
```

Comment: You didn't specify where `list_country` comes from .... therefore the answer doesn't work now

Answer (score 2):

You can split the `address_countries` into a list and then use `n_distinct`.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(n_countries = map_int(address_countries, ~
                                 .x %>% 
                                 str_trim %>% 
                                 str_split(" ") %>% 
                                 unlist() %>% 
                                 n_distinct))
```

`map_int` applies the function following after the comme to each element of `address_countries` and outputs an integer 
`str_trim` removes whitespaces at the beginning and end of the vector 
`str_split` splits the vector, using `" "` as splitting pattern 
`unlist` turns the result of str_split into a vector 
`n_distinct` counts the unique elements of the resulting vector

**Data**

```
df <- tibble(address_countries = c("China China", "China China China", "China China", 
                                   "China China", "China China China China China China", 
                                   "China China Uk China"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want:

```
ac$n_countries <- lengths(lapply(strsplit(ac$countries, split = ' '), unique))
```

The result:

```
> ac
    countries n_countries
1       Chian           1
2 China China           1
3    China UK           2
```

The data:

```
ac <- data.frame(countries = c("Chian","China China","China UK"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```