# Total unique words in a column - R

Tags: r, sum, strsplit

I am interested in counting unique words that appear in a column. 
Rather than getting unique words per row as expained in [Count unique/dinstinct words into a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621428/count-unique-dinstinct-words-into-a-new-column)
I'm interested in getting one answer which counts all unique entries in that column.
In the following example the total unique countries are 3: 
China 
Australia and 
Korea

Is there a short way of getting this sum?
I am still learning R therefore I have limited knowledge.

```
Countries

China  Australia

Australia

China China 

Korea Korea Korea Korea
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `split` the column 'Countries' by space, `unlist`, and get the `length` of `unique` words

```
length(unique(unlist(strsplit(df1$Countries, " "))))
#[1] 3
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    separate_rows(Countries) %>% 
    distinct() %>%
    nrow
#[1] 3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Countries = c("China Australia", "Australia", 
 "China China", "Korea Korea Korea Korea")), .Names = "Countries",
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I just tried the tidyverse solution, I am wondering why the two methods give different result?
Based on my understanding, the tidyverse approach is giving the final sum as the sum of unique entries per row.
The earlier method apparently is giving the total sum of unique words in that column (which is what I wanted).

Comment: @SadiaN I get the same result with the data I showed.  The `separate_rows` splits the words and expands the column, then `distinct` gets the distinct elements, nrow gives the number of rows.  so, it is basically the same methodology

Comment: Could you kindly explain the second method @akrun, what is the meaning of separate_rows, why do we have nrow at the end?

Comment: @SaidaN In the second method, by calling `distinct`, we get the dataset with the unique rows and from there, with `nrow` we are looking for the number of rows of the dataset.  `separate_rows` will split a row into different rows based on the pattern provided\

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the pattern of the data you provided:

```
length(unique(unlist(str_split(data$Countries, ' '))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
   separate_rows(col,sep=",") %>% 
   count(col)
```